# jquery disable post back on button Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery UI and Autocomplete func.(Combobox) and I interested in this part.

```
$("<button>&nbsp;</button>")
                    .attr("tabIndex", -1)
                    .attr("title", "Show All Items")
                    .insertAfter(input)
                    .button({
                      icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                      },
                      text: false
```

My problem is when I use ASP.net, this button do PostBack, but I not need this because my list of items then gone. How can I override this  behavior of button.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an id to your button

```
$("#yourbutton").click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

give your button a click handler and return false and prevent default propagation

```
.click( function(event) { event.preventDefault(); return false; } );
```

tacked onto the end should give you the least of what you want.

The thing is that the button is being inserted inside a form. Any button inside a form causes the form to postback. That's default behavior for a browser, and is considered expected.

Does this help clarify why this is occuring on your asp.net application?

You may not need to return false, but I usually do.